# EF Core - Cannot create a relationship between [table] and [table] because a relationship already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have simple (turns out not really simple) tables with reusing existing type

```
[Table("SensorConfiguration", Schema = "capture")]
public class SensorConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid CaptureDeviceId { get; set; }

    public CaptureDevice CaptureDevice { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public List<BaseConfiguration> Transports { get; set; }

    public List<ProtocolConfiguration> Protocols { get; set; }

    public List<ProtocolConfiguration> MLModels { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset LastModifiedAt { get; set; }
}

[Table("BaseConfiguration", Schema = "capture")]
public class BaseConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SensorConfigurationId { get; set; }

    public SensorConfiguration SensorConfiguration { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProtocolConfiguration", Schema = "capture")]
public class ProtocolConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    public List<string> Transports { get; set; }
}
```

Which I'm trying to configure as

```
internal class SensorConfigConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SensorConfiguration>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SensorConfiguration> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(b => b.MLModels)
            .WithOne(b => b.SensorConfiguration);

        builder.HasMany(b => b.Protocols)
            .WithOne(b => b.SensorConfiguration);

        builder.HasMany(b => b.Transports)
            .WithOne(b => b.SensorConfiguration);
    }
}
```

But when adding migration I get

```
Cannot create a relationship between 'SensorConfiguration.Protocols' and 'ProtocolConfiguration.SensorConfiguration' because a relationship already exists between 'SensorConfiguration.MLModels' and 'ProtocolConfiguration.SensorConfiguration'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship.
```

I do understand that EF cannot make a difference between `Protocol` and `MLModel` in a single table, but how can I fix that?

Comment: See inheritance configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: `b.SensorConfiguration` can't be the inverse end of two 1:n associations.